# Why is the sentinel mandatory in this call to iter?

Tags: python

I am not used to seeing a sentinel while converting an iterable object to an iterator. Here is the code I am analyzing:

```
import re
NAME = r'(?P<NAME>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)'
NUM  = r'(?P<NUM>\d+)'
PLUS = r'(?P<PLUS>\+)'
TIMES = r'(?P<TIMES>\*)'
EQ    = r'(?P<EQ>=)'
WS    = r'(?P<WS>\s+)'
master_pat = re.compile('|'.join([NAME, NUM, PLUS, TIMES, EQ, WS]))

from collections import namedtuple
Token = namedtuple('Token', ['type','value'])

def generate_tokens(pat, text):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    scanner = pat.scanner(text)
    for m in iter(scanner.match,None):
        yield Token(m.lastgroup, m.group())
# Example use
for tok in generate_tokens(master_pat, 'foo = 42'):
    print(tok)
```

Why is the sentinel mandatory ?
I did not expect to see this error:

```
(Pdb) it2=iter(scanner.match)     
*** TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The method `scanner.match` is not iterable. In general, `for x in iter(y)` is anyways superfluous, with `for` calling `iter` on its own (`for x in y` is identical).

Comment: @L3viathan so if the method scanner.match is not iterable, we build an iterable with the iter function. I do not understand how it works, i can't apply this process to any method ...

Comment: You can't just make an iterable out of anything. The result of _calling_ `scanner.match` is iterable, but you still don't need to call `iter()` explicitly: `for m in scanner.match(): ...`.

Comment: I tried the syntax suggested which do not work on my side: >>> for m in scanner.match():
...     print(m)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>      
TypeError: 're.Match' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help for the [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) built-in function states:

> Get an iterator from an object.  In the first form, the argument must
> supply its own iterator, or be a sequence.
> In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.

In the first form, the object passed to `iter` is already iterable, so `iter` can create an iterator and iterate until the iterator is exhausted.

In the second form (as seen in the question), the first argument passed to `iter` is a callable.  `iter` needs the sentinel argument to to determine when to stop calling the callable.

The second form is equivalent to:

```
def iter(some_func, sentinel):
    while True:
        retval = some_func()
        if retval == sentinel:
            break
        yield retval
```